# Trying to get OAuth2 authentication token from Reddit without the user interaction PHP

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, reddit

I am trying to get the authentication token from Reddit without any user interaction. The user does not need to click anything or also does not need to have an account.

What currently is happening is that I see this:
[image: reddit interaction]

I would like my visitor not needing to be clicking anything and site just loads.
The code I used is from: https://github.com/jcleblanc/reddit-php-sdk

Then applying the information from here https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/OAuth2#application-only-oauth regarding grant_type and making sure the `$url` is ok

```
<?php
require("reddit.php");
$reddit = new reddit();

//GET ACCESS AND REFRESH TOKEN
$url ='https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token';
$clientId = 'myclientID'; 
$clientSecret = 'mysecret';

//SET POST VARIABLES
$fields = array (
    'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
    'response_type' => 'code',
    'state' => 'someblaandmorebla'
);

//URL-IFY DATA FOR POST
$field_string = http_build_query($fields);

echo $field_string;

//OPEN CONNECTION
$ch = curl_init($url);

//SET CURL DATA
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode($clientId . ':' . $clientSecret) ) );
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $field_string);

//EXECUTE POST
echo curl_exec($ch);

//CLOSE CONNECTION
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

for the sake of the reddit rules I am trying to fetch the token.
I am just fetching: https://www.reddit.com/r/news/new.json and can do it without the token already.  It's just that I don't want my visitor to go through extra interactions.

When creating the reddit app I have tried Web app and script.

I hope it is possible what I want. Thank you for reading

Comment: I feel like any answer here will be a breach of security to Reddits user protection systems. If you could authenticate and grab the users token then theoretically, any website could post on your behalf without asking for permission...

Comment: I did not read the reddit oauth2 docs but generally speaking; If you are going to authenticate using client_credentials grant type; it is useless to request 'code' as the response type. You already share your secret, communicating in machine level and don't use user browser. Btw; even if you authenticate as a client; if you request a user resource, user will face the same screen. Those are different things. If you don't want the user to see the authorization screen, you have to be a trusted client in reddit (oauth provider) or use the password grant type at the first place.